# How to mount .MDS file?

Tags: 18.04, mount

I've tried using commands but all it gives me is:

```
mount: [DIRECTORY]: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on 
/dev/loop29, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

it works with ISO file but not MDS or MDF? help

Comment: when posting a question with an error notice please copy/paste command used and the error notice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It SHOULD be:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/mdf/ 
mount -o loop -t iso9660 {file}.mdf /mnt/mdf
```

---

If that does not work you can also install iat and convert it to ISO

```
sudo apt install iat
```

From `man iat`:

```
DESCRIPTION
   iat   (Iso9660  Analyzer Tool) is a tool for detecting the structure of
   many types of CD-ROM image file formats, such as BIN,  MDF,  PDI,  CDI,
   NRG, and B5I, and  converting them into ISO-9660.

   If output file name is not defined, then STDOUT will be used instead.
```

Or you can also install [Furius ISO Mount](https://launchpad.net/furiusisomount/) with ...

```
sudo apt install furiusisomount
```

> Furius ISO Mount is a simple application for mounting ISO, IMG, BIN, MDF and NG image files even without burning them to disk.

Comment: Interesting to know!

Comment: This does not use the .mds file at all. So bad blocks will not be reflected.

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cdemu/ppa
sudo apt install cdemu-client
```

Run it (GUI - appears on panel), click on "device" then mount MDS file
Profit!